# How to delete a single element on list of list?

Tags: python, list

SO i want to delete item on list of list

```
list1 =[[1],[2],[3]]
list1.pop(0)
print("listUpdate",list1)
```

this prints:

```
listUpdate [[2], [3]]
```

desired result:

```
listUpdate [[], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: `list1[0].pop(0)` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
list1[0].pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just replace it?

```
list1 =[[1],[2],[3]]
list1[0] = []
print("listUpdate",list1)
```

output:

```
[[], [2], [3]]
```